# Login button and server-side authentication

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-authentication, facebook-login

I added a facebook login-button to my website, that works great, I can successfully make javascript calls to the API using `FB.api()`.

But now I would like to know from the server side if the user is logged in, and send some user information from client side to server side. Or even better if possible : use the client side authentication to make API calls from the server side.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP-sdk works great with javascript-sdk

- refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/
- refer to https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/  This example
  shows how to auth php with javascript.

Comment: Thanks but this is a java web application.

Comment: @KayKay If i come across a java-sdk i will post to you.

EDIT: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk for android not sure if this you can use or pick apart.